# using UTF-8 characters in action script

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, utf-8, flash-cs3

I want to use UTF-8 characters in my action script code. how can I do?

my code:

```
var menu_label:Array = new Array("Ş", "Ç", "Ğ" , "Ü");
```

Comment: Using the characters in code should be OK, as long as the source file is saved as UTF-8.

Comment: try `System.useCodePage = true;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to embed the font and specify the unicode range. There's a good description on how to do that [here](http://www.spikything.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/06/how-to-embed-fonts-in-pure-as3/).

Comment: It's also important to make sure that the embedded font actually _contains_ the character sets you need.